# Is there a generic "describe" method for boto3 objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am imagining something like this ... is there a method that serves a similar purpose? This will help me learn quickly.

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my-cli-profile', region_name='us-east-1')
cf = session.resource('cloudformation')
print (cf.describe_attributes())
print (cf.describe_methods())
```

Comment: _Why_ do you ask? If you are seeking a programmatic listing of API calls, you could extract it from the [botocore project](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data).

Comment: at this point i am simply learning about the boto3 SDK and the methods it supports. Using a jupyter notebook to progress one step at a time as I learn about a new resource or client. Instead of jumping between jupyter and boto3 documentation site, I thought it might be useful to access documentation programmatically.

can you kindly point to how I might access the botocore documentation programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use standard Python's [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function. For example:

```
print(dir(cf))
```

gives out:

```
['Event', 'Stack', 'StackResource', 'StackResourceSummary', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'create_stack', 'get_available_subresources', 'meta', 'stacks']
```

There is also [vars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
print(vars(cf))
```

which gives:

```
{'meta': ResourceMeta('cloudformation', identifiers=[])}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin - i learnt a new thing today, though it doesnt seem to provide all the properties or methods of this object for some reason. will explore further.

Comment: @Zoltar No problem. Can you clarify which methods `dir` does not list? `dir` is the primary tool to inspect objects in Python.